# Fitting impedance of simple randles circuit to Fourier transform formula

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, circuit

I have this simple circuit that i want to find parameters of,

[image: Randles model]

and its real-world magnitude frequency response derived from impedance spectroscopy.

[image]
(magnitude frequency response.Frequency is 10-10000Hz with 10Hz step.)

R1=100Ω, R2=2200Ω, C=1E-7 F

Now, i have derived the fourier transform of this impedance:

[image: ft]

Whose magnitude i found:

[image: response]

However trying to fit this last equation with matlab CFTOOL gives nonsense. What am i doing wrong??

[image: cftool result]

Comment: Formula looks good. is it possible that the start values for the fit are off? As R and C differ by orders of magnitude this easily fails.  High frequency limit gives R1 approx 200 Ohm. Low freq. limit is R1 + R2. approx 2200 so R2 approx 2000. As there is a significant change st f approx 4000 Hz I'd make the guess 2 pi f R2 approx 1 so C approx 1e-8. Either scale your formula to kOhm and nF or put the according starting values.

Comment: @mikuszefski you were right. Scaling the capacitor with 1e-7 or less in front worked. Also cleaner solution i found changing the fit options,particularly the termination tolerance TolX to 1e-10 and the constraints, starting points to 0 as well as lower values to 0.  I hope their function was explained by matlab but i cant find much. Anyway i suppose it now works. Thanks a bunch! You just helped me get in a paper!

Comment: Good to hear, I hope you get a fair referee. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the new fit options: I don't know really if the function termination tolerance is significant, it seems it helps to reduce it to 1e-10.

[image]